# Upper Bound on Supremum of Expected Value

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $\left( \Omega, F, P\right)$ be a probability space, where $P$ is a probability measure on $\mathbb{X} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, so that $P(\mathbb{X}) = 1$.

For all integer $i \geq 1$, consider the function $f_i: \mathbb{X}^i \rightarrow \{0,1,\ldots, m\}$.

Assume that for all $M \geq m$, $$\sup_{ X \in \mathbb{X}^M } f_M(X) = \sup_{ x \in \mathbb{X}^m } f_m(x). $$

Let $\mathbb{E}_i[\cdot]$ denote the expected value, i.e., for all integer $i \geq 1$,
$$ \mathbb{E}_i\left[ f_i(\cdot) \right] := \int_{ \mathbb{X}^i } f_i( y ) P^i(dy). $$

Question 1. Under what conditions on the $f_i$'s the following inequality holds?
$$ \sup_{M \geq m} \mathbb{E}_M[ f_M(\cdot) ] \leq \mathbb{E}_m\left[ \sup_{ z \subset \cdot } f_i(z) \right] $$
where $z$ is of appropriate dimension.
The notation $z \subset x$, with $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, stands for $z_j \in \{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \}$ for all $j = 1, 2, \ldots, i$.

Question 2. Generally speaking, are there know upper bounds for the supremum of an expeceted value?

Comment: Again? As previously explained, without some specific hypothesis on the setting, the only available bound is the trivial one you call "loose" at the end.

Comment: Ok, I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: "Accordingly" to what? The function is still so general that "the only available bound is the trivial one you call "loose" at the end".

Comment: Acconding to your comment. Now the question is about finding conditions on $f_i$'s under which a precise inequality holds. Perhaps you should read the question before commenting.

Comment: "Acconding to your comment." Certainly not. "Perhaps you should read the question before commenting." Right, I had forgotten how you treated those helping you... Silly me.

Comment: Did, please avoid pretending you are trying to help: nobody trusts you! Also, please take a look on your comments like "Again?", "Accondingly to what?" and so on.

Comment: You know exactly what "Again" and "Accordingly to what?" refer to. And "nobody trusts you" is sweet. Amongst your 10 last questions, only one (on a different theme than your pet subject) got an answer. Does this tell you something? (But maybe there is a badge for that?)